# Sending Email from EditText in Android App

Tags: android, email

I'm having an issue similar to this: [Adding text from edit text field into an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882680/adding-text-from-edit-text-field-into-an-email) . I am able to do what this is doing, but how could I send the email straight from a submit button, instead of having it compose an email in a default email client. This should be able to be sent with as anonymous and not need to be sent by default from an installed email client.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download JavaMail API:
Download: https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home

You need an SMTP server, also username and password for auth.

```
          String host="your smtp";
          final String user="from email address";//change accordingly
          final String password="frm email password";//change accordingly

          String to="to email";//change accordingly

           //Get the session object
           Properties props = new Properties();
           props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);
           props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

           javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                      protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(user,password);
                      }
                    });

                   //Compose the message
                    try {
                     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
                     message.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
                     message.setSubject("javatpoint");
                     message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");

                    //send the message
                     javax.mail.Transport.send(message);

                     System.out.println("message sent successfully...");

                     } 
                    catch (MessagingException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

## There is no way to send an email silently, without either

- letting the user know and accept it first (by using intents and an email provider)
- or asking for the username and password before and using an email API as above (the user will implicitly give you the approval to send/receive emails by entering those values)

**And that is a very good thing!** There are too many security concerns otherwise. If you ever find a way, please post it as a bug report in android.

Workaround:
You need to use an email API such as JavaMail:

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app)

Answer (score -1):

There are some anonymous mailers that have APIs that you could use. But I would suggest you not do this. I actually agree with @DheeB 100%. I can't up vote yet.

Here is an example of one such service: http://api.temp-mail.ru/  It's in Russian but it can be translated. Again, I don't recommend but trying to answer your question.