# How to get the value of Edit Text via email

Tags: android, email

I am developing an android app in which i need feedback option. I use the default `Email Intent` code but it's growing old you know, i need some code for sending email via the same app. Every thing they type in an `Edit Text`, should be the email body. You may have seen some apps using that & it saves the feedback messages also. It is just like a messanger. How can i?

Comment: May just be misreading but your question and title seem to differ

Comment: I added two more lines, please read it once again.

Comment: and sorry for my horrible english.

Comment: @RandomGuy take a look on this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882680/adding-text-from-edit-text-field-into-an-email?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

i would sent the email message with an ajax call to a webpage http://yourdomainname.com/sendemail.php

the page will recieve the email msg as post or get parameters 
and send it to your email

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting a button and onbuttonclick you can send a email with edit text values as body.
**code for buttonclick**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             String[] recipients = new String[]{"my@email.com", "",};
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is email's message");
              emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                        "name:"+edt1.getText().toString()+'\n'+"address:"+edt2.getText().toString()+'\n'+"city:"+edt3.getText().toString()+'\n'+'\n'+edt4.getText().toString()+'\n'+'\n'+"Sent from the Lads to Leaders/Leaderettes Android App.");

              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
              finish();

        }
    });
```